# VBS password protected image

Tags: image, vbscript, passwords, message, box

I'm not a programmer and i need help.
How to combine this two scripts into one?
Then i will convert this to EXE and give as present on Tank Style pendrive :).

```
pass=inputbox("Password?")
if pass="fish" then msgbox("Correct Password!") else msgbox("Incorrect Password!")
```

AND

```
Set objExplorer = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

With objExplorer "
    .Navigate "about:blank"
    .ToolBar = 0
    .StatusBar = 0
    .Left = 200
    .Top = 200
    .Width = 650
    .Height = 440
    .Visible = 1
    .Document.Title = "Kocham cie Maciek!"
    .Document.Body.InnerHTML = _
        "<center>Kocham cie Maciek <3<br><br><img src='http://www.crystalclearsports.net/file/2016/07/use_love_quotes_for_him_and_inspire_romantic_vitality.jpg' height=336 width=600></center>"
" 
End With
```

When someone type good password it show Picture1, if bad Picture2.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this!

```
Dim MyPassword, objExplorer
MyPassword = InputBox("Enter the Password and Press 'OK' ", "Password")
MyPassword = Trim(MyPassword) 

If MyPassword = "" Then
    Msgbox "No Password is entered"
Else
    Set objExplorer = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With objExplorer 
        .Navigate "about:blank"
        .ToolBar = 0
        .StatusBar = 0
        .Left = 200
        .Top = 200
        .Width = 650
        .Height = 440
        .Visible = 1
        .Document.Title = "Kocham cie Maciek!"
    End With 
    If StrComp(MyPassword, "FISH", 1) = 0 Then
        ' Correct Password
        Msgbox "The Password is Correct"
        objExplorer.Document.Body.InnerHTML = "<center>Kocham cie Maciek <3<br><br><img src='http://www.crystalclearsports.net/file/2016/07/use_love_quotes_for_him_and_inspire_romantic_vitality.jpg' height=336 width=600></center>'" 
    Else
        Msgbox "Incorrect Password"
        objExplorer.Document.Body.InnerHTML = "<center>Kocham cie Maciek <3<br><br><img src='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' height=336 width=600></center>'" 
    End If
End if
```

you missed the second image, update the XXXX with the location of second image you would want to show!!

Comment: Thank you very much!!! It was exactly what i want. It is part of Christmas present for my best friend from his girlfriend :). Merry Christmas and a Happy New Year to You :)